# Cloud load data from web Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am new in Azure and cloud computing and I want to do a little project in Azure. My idea is to get some data from a webpage and then store it in an Azure SQL database.

I want it to be an automatic script that will run every hour and save the results to the database. What service should I choose in the Azure platform? Worker service?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Why do you need a script to insert data in the database coming from a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar recently with more complexity(using queues and service bus)

For this Automatic background tasks Worker Role is the ideal choice

use Quartz.NEt for scheduling your job

This link is perfect for your needs just follow the tutorial and you will get it running in no time

[Worker role with Quartz.NET](http://mattrandle.me/azure-worker-role-and-quartz-net/)